# Use Webform Results in another webform content type

Tags: webforms

I am creating a website for my department at work using Drupal 7. I have a webform designed in a page named Registration in the website. When a user fills this form in and submits, it  sends a confirmation to me. I am also able to view the submissions using the Results tab in the webform using admin rights.

Now I am creating an other page(named 'approve request') for an editor role who approves the submission of the user. This Approve request page has been created in the content type that enables the webform. Now, I need the webform results from the Registration page to appear in the Approve request page. This will enable the Editor to view the Registration results and approve them.

How do I retrieve the results from the registration page to the Approval page? I looked at various sources and could not find a good answer. Please let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can programmatically modify the form of **Approve Request** webform using **hook_form_alter()** function. In this form you can retrieve the previous webform submission entries and append in the **Approve Request** form.

You can retrieve previous webform submission using following snippet:

```
include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') .'/includes/webform.submissions.inc');
$nid = arg(1); // need to hard-code nid if this is a custom page you can manage dynamically also
$sid = $_GET['sid'];
$submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid);
```

Comment: Thanks. I made the change in the hook_form_alter in the webform module. The Registration page is node 24 and hence added the following code in my function. It did not get the results for me. `function webform_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) { include_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'webform') .'/includes/webform.submissions.inc'); $nid = arg(24); // need to hard-code nid if this is a custom page you can manage dynamically also $sid = $_GET['sid']; $submission = webform_get_submission($nid, $sid); }` I am not sure if I am missing something.

Comment: In Stack Exchange we accepts answers to tell thanks.. Please accept the answer for better understanding of other people also.

Comment: since it was not working for me I wanted to confirm it with you before I could accept the answer. Apologies. Please see my comment above for details on the snippet that did not work for me. Thank you.

Comment: just a moment.. sharing you the detailed code

Comment: but at $nid = arg(1) should be there, why you return arg(24). arg(1) means www.example.com/node/24 then arg(0) is 'node' and arg(1) is 24 which is 'nid'

Comment: Ah! Okay. I misunderstood that the `$nid` variable has to be assigned to the node number of the desired webform result which has to appear in another page. Since the webform result was in node 24 I assigned it to that. Thank you for the input!

Comment: Just tried the change of arg(1) . It did not work either!